# android - what is the difference between android ram and pc's ram

Tags: android, ram, processor

Yesterday I tried to open a *.txt file larger than 3 MB with android. Why can't android open it?
Previously I had tried to open that file with Windows with the same RAM capacity and Processor speed.

What exactly is the difference between android and PC needed to open the file?

Comment: Depends more on how the text editor is implemented than on the platform/architecture/OS.

Comment: Android can open that file of course. Please show your code. Another thing is if Android can place it in memory or handle the file correctly. Any errors? P!ease tell them!

Answer (score 1):

There are several differences between smartphones RAM and PC RAM.

1) A PC typically has one or more sockets holding RAM chips soldered onto a pluggable card. This allows easy upgrading and replacement, but does increase the physical size of the system. For mechanical reasons phone RAM is normally soldered directly to the motherboard, or even in a "package-on-package" on top of the phone's CPU.

2) DIMM/SODIMM memory modules for a PC are normally 64-bit data width. You will typically have eight separate RAM ICs, each 8 bits wide, connected to separate 8-bit data buses but sharing address and control pins. Extra-large DIMMs can be "dual rank" and have chips on both sides for a total of 16; these are structured logically as an 8x2 grid. Each 8-bit chunk of the data bus has two chips on it, one handling the low half and one for the high half. By comparison, a phone typically has a single 16-bit wide RAM IC.

3) A PC's memory is normally a high-performance memory standard such as DDR3, while phone memory is normally power optimized like LPDDR3. Among other things DDR3 runs at 1.5V while LPDDR3 runs at 1.2.